# How do I fix a TypeError regarding a ViewChild element that actually works?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, error-handling, viewchild

This is the HTML component where checkbox is

```html
 <mat-checkbox class="dashboard-content-custom-select-option" id="dashboard-all-checkbox" #allSelector [indeterminate]="someCheckboxesActive()" [checked]="allCheckboxesActive()" (click)="toggleAllSelection($event)">Alle </mat-checkbox>
```

The Select all Mat-Checkbox is checked if all of the upper checkboxes are checked. It is also checked if clicked on while some checkboxes are left empty and all of them are checked.

```js
export class DashboardContentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('dashboard-all-checkbox') allSelect: MatCheckbox;

toggleAllSelection(event) { // toggle checkbox is controlled from here
    console.log(this.allSelect);
    if ( event.currentTarget.id === 'dashboard-all-checkbox' && this.selectedValues.length === 6) {
      this.dashboardContentForm.get('dashboardContentValue').setValue([]); 
      this.allSelect.checked = false; // unchecks the checkbox
    } else if ( (this.selectedValues.length < 6  && event.currentTarget.id === 'dashboard-all-checkbox') )  {
      this.dashboardContentForm.get('dashboardContentValue').setValue(
         [ ...this.displayDashboardContentValues.map((dv) => dv.key), ...[0]]
      );
      this.allSelect.toggle(); //checks the checkbox
    }
  }
}
```

In this TS file, 6 upper checkboxes must all be active for the Select All checkbox to be active.
Otherwise if less than 6 are active, it becomes indeterminate.

To be precise, everything works fine.
However, the only problem is that I get TypeErrors although the checkbox does whatevery it is supposed to do. If checkbox's id is used, everything is fine(which is the only way that works here in my case). If I use the #allSelector, it is different.
How do I prevent these errors from occuring?
Besides, you can ignore the grey highlighting in the dropdown, it isn't relevant.

if the select all checkbox is clicked and checked
[image]

[image]

if the select all checkbox is clicked and unchecked
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ViewChild` should be pointing to `#allSelector`(local template variable) and not `id="dashboard-all-checkbox"` (id selector).

By changing the `ViewChild` to lookup `allSelector` should fill value.

```
@ViewChild('allSelector') allSelect: MatCheckbox;
```

Comment: I did try this but for some reason the checkbox gets checked where it isn't supposed to be. If the dropdown is empty, the checkbox is on . If the dropdown is full, the checkbox is empty. That is really strange and  I don't know how to solve it otherwise so far.
It only works with the id that is the problem

Comment: @DrDave96 wait, you are saying with `@ViewChild('dashboard-all-checkbox')` it used to be working?

Comment: yes exactly. Only with that, everything works. But there is a TypeError unfortunately and I need to fix it. Is there a way to the id correctly without any error in Angular?

Comment: @DrDave96 strange, can you check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzw3j4)? its not working `id` selector

Comment: my element is also called undefined in the console. So I have the same problem like you do. I need to check further. Do you know where the same problem's  also been discussed?

Comment: @DrDave96 the stackblitz provided in last comment was not working, you can easily fix that by suggested answer. I'm not able to understand what exactly is failing further. Can you please reproduce the problem here inside [`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdm6t7), and share it back with me? I can have a further look into it.

Comment: I will need time to understand it fully honestly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246638/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-drdave96).

Comment: Update: It now works with a selector instead of an id but the error is still there

Comment: Glad something worked, can you please share more context, whats not working now? and if you want more attention. I would recommend you to open another question. May be other people can also jump in. Thanks :)

Comment: It is a general problem it seems as the error also comes if the selector is used so I must get the element properly